# Track users position for a longer period of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, location, cllocationmanager

I am building an app, that works as an alarm-service. The app is sending data about the users location to our server every 10-minutes.

The problem is that the app will stop sending the data after a few hours or days. I have tried to find more info about this and have compared our app with the performance of the app "Moves" that keeps on tracking for weeks. In their help section you can read about the most common reasons why the tracking goes down (http://www.moves-app.com/help), but that doesn't help.

They must be using some trick that we don't. I guess they use several methods to accomplish this.

- Anyone what has successfully build an iOS app with similar functionality that can lead me in the right direction?

My code looks like this:

AppDelegate:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _locManager = [[MYLocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self._locManager start];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self._locManager restart];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self._locManager restart];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self._locManager stop];
}
```

MYLocationManager:

```
- (void)start
{
    [self _invokeLocationUpdates];
}


- (void)stop
{
    [self _killLocationUpdates];
}

- (void)restart
{
    [self _killLocationUpdates];
    [self _invokeLocationUpdates];
}

- (void)_killLocationUpdates
{
    if (self._locationManager != nil) {
        [self._locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];    
        self._locationManager = nil;
    }
}


- (void)_invokeLocationUpdates
{
    if (self._locationManager == nil) {
        self._locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self._locationManager.delegate = self;

        self._locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

        if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
            self._locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
            self._locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
        }
        else {
            self._locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
            self._locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
        }

        [self._locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    // sending location info to server
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MYSEC_NOTIFICATION_POSITION_UPDATE object:self];
}
```

In info.plist file we have:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
<string>location</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Significant-Change Location Service. Basically if your app is suspended or terminated, when the significant-change location service receives data it wakes up your app and gives it some time to process the data. You can read more info at [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).